# How to make several objects free fall at different keyframes?

Tags: python

Im strugling at simulating free fall physics interaction. What i want to achieve is resumed in this steps:

1)object 1 falls from certain height

2)object 1 is set to passive at frame (lets say frame=50). When i consider.

3)object 2 is added into scene at frame 50, it free falls and collides with object 1.

3)Repeat

I got everything settled except simulating interaction. I can't make objects fall at certain keyframe and make active/passive transformations at that specific key frame.

I must do it via script, I need to automate the process.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much.

Comment: show us what you got so far

Comment: Im triying to simulate blind constructiton of Homogeneous Low-crested Structures (HLCS) made of concrete armor units.

I defined serveral functions that I want to call in order, 
-cubipod(x,y,z,Dn).concrete armor unit
-HLCS(Dn,a,b,rows,columns,layer) 
triangular grid a·b, i·j rows and columns and #layer
-activelayer(layer). Transform #layer
-pasivelayer(layer) Transform #layer
So, my target -> call HLCS layer 1, let it fall, make it passive when all armor units rests, transform everything into passive interaction and call HLCs at layer 2. repeat

Answer (score 0):

Use the bpy.data.objects[“Obj Name”].rigid_body.dynamic or …rigid_body.enabled property